# Probability of hitting a two-dimensional random vector into a rectangle

Tags: probability-theory

We know that P{a≤X1<b, c≤X2<d}=F(b, d)+F(a, d)−F(b, c)−F(a, d),
where F(a,b)=P{X<a, X2<b}
But what is the probability:
P{a≤X1≤b, c≤X2≤d}?

Comment: How is your second probability different from the first probability?

Comment: I was told they are different, but I don't understand how, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Oh I see, the inequalities are strict vs non-strict. You should be able to get it by replacing $b$ and $d$ with $b^+$ and $d^+$, the limiting values from the right.

Comment: Although I would expect the right side of the first equation to be $F(b,d)-F(a,d)-F(b,c)+F(a,c)$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought so, but I was not sure and did not know how to correctly describe the answer. And yes, I have a typo in the formula, sorry.